# Why would the metaplex token-metadata program identify a token with decimals and no edition as ProgrammableNonFungible?

Tags: metaplex, metaplex-js

Per the [Metaplex token-standard documentation](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/token-standard), "the Token Standard is set automatically by the Token Metadata program and cannot be manually updated" and "If the token has no (Master) Edition account (ensuring its supply can be > 1) and uses zero decimals places, it is a FungibleAsset."

However, attempting to use createMetadataAccountV3 from `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` on a [token with no edition and with decimals](https://solscan.io/token/CRAKn86eAqbVkiqFTY9pu9CokxHskCqbuuJjFyphwCMk?cluster=devnet) results in the error `0x99`, "Instruction not supported for ProgrammableNonFungible assets".

The calling code:

```
const mint = new PublicKey(mintPubkeyString);

const endpoint = clusterApiUrl(cluster);
const umi = createUmi(endpoint);

const mplProgramId = new PublicKey(
  "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"
);
const [metadata] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
  [Buffer.from("metadata"), mplProgramId.toBytes(), mint.toBytes()],
  mplProgramId
);

const umiMintAuthorityKeypair: UmiKeypair = {
  publicKey: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mintAuthorityKeypair.publicKey),
  secretKey: mintAuthorityKeypair.secretKey,
};
const mintAuthoritySigner: UmiSigner = createSignerFromKeypair(
  umi,
  umiMintAuthorityKeypair
);
umi.use(keypairIdentity(umiMintAuthorityKeypair));

tokenMetadata = {
  name: "KTest",
  symbol: "KTEST",
  uri: "https://foo.com/bar",
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: 200,
  collection: null,
  creators: null,
  uses: null,
};

const args: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs = {
  data: tokenMetadata,
  isMutable: true,
  collectionDetails: null,
};

const accounts: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts = {
  metadata: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(metadata),
  mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mint),
  payer: mintAuthoritySigner,
  mintAuthority: mintAuthoritySigner,
  updateAuthority: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mintAuthorityKeypair.publicKey),
};

const builder = createMetadataAccountV3(umi, { ...accounts, ...args });
builder.getInstructions().forEach((ix) => console.log(ix));
const confirmResult = await builder.sendAndConfirm(umi);
console.log("Transaction confirmation: ", confirmResult);
```

This results in the transaction data

```
data: Uint8Array(84) [
   33,   5,   0,   0,   0,  75,  84, 101, 115, 116,   5,   0,
    0,   0,  75,  84,  69,  83,  84,  54,   0,   0,   0, 104,
  116, 116, 112, 115,  58,  47,  47, 107, 105, 114, 111, 115,
   99, 111, 105, 110,  46,  99, 111, 109,  47, 116, 111, 107,
  101, 110,  45, 109, 101, 116,  97, 100,  97, 116,  97,  47,
  107, 105, 114, 111, 115,  45, 115, 111, 108,  97, 110,  97,
   46, 106, 115, 111, 110, 200,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   0
]
```

With the full transaction (in base58) being `T7Z6dqJLpe476CpJLkDe7ewfurXBWMfL9mwMbK7rnPYkfcQ76YoSbaBuKg8wzpbx4spMwSxQqCcEL5HNDAqjX46CUPMXD92XGWPyvjy9kgRdNy9AYd6zPpGzrSRee7JYjNryqTssZZ68RV9pZYyMRKX941BBtyEiHBPkjLK9cybzQNjZwRxhc2ooTKvYKBzFunYYv7bUwwi55TRfbUKvDRsnxy8egkAwbJc9ARyTe6r1M3zDw5sjcLL81VLy8Wm7akPYF4zTvMpybtyrn9wNSW8oVxkZqqX94y8LWqgvHomxPqPRWEGPV2eXxprEWpT87UP3rDCEfMazWA3EWSff5AzUxTEuo5q`

Comment: Hi, can you please show how you're calling the instruction? Sample code would be great, or a serialized transaction or a transaction with skipPreflight = true also works.

Comment: @KartikSoneji Thank you, I have added the relevant code as well as the serialized transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the legacy `createMetadataAccountV3` instruction to create `ProgrammableNonFungible`s.

Instead, you must use the newest handlers to create and manage your pNFTs. Namely, you will need to use the `create` and `mint` instructions within the same transaction. However, when using the Umi SDK, you can use the `createProgrammableNft` helper function like so:

```
import { percentAmount, generateSigner } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi'
import { createProgrammableNft } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

const mint = generateSigner(umi)
await createProgrammableNft(umi, {
  mint,
  name: 'My Programmable NFT',
  uri: 'https://example.com/my-programmable-nft.json',
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(5.5),
}).sendAndConfirm(umi)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the token in this case is a fungible asset.

Comment: I'm afraid there is currently no such thing as a programmable fungible asset. To create a non-programmable fungible asset, you may use the `createFungible` helper function instead.

Comment: The object in this case is not to create an asset, but to create metadata for an existing, non-programmable, fungible token.

Comment: Gotcha! Sorry for the confusion. These create helpers are basically a juxtaposition of the create and mint instructions. What you want is the `createV1` function which will only create the Metadata account if the mint account already exists. Technically you should be able to do this with the legacy `createMetadataAccountV3` instruction though. The full transaction log would be helpful to debug why the program think you’re trying to create a pNFT.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, That's a misleading error message in the source of Metaplex, the error gets thrown if your asset is pNFT **or Token2022**, the latter seems to be your issue.

I made a PR here to fix that, if it does get merged, should be available in newer versions.

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/pull/79